# Is there a way to track if a user prints a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, printing

Is there a way to track if a user prints a web page?

Thanks,
Graham

Comment: What about if a user took a screenshot, or used their digital camera, or downloaded your webpage as a complete page, unplugged their network card, and then printed that? You're fighting a losing battle.

Comment: @Kyle: OP haven't shown the intention to block users from printing. He might as well be trying to track user's behavior for another purpose.

Comment: @Kyle - My purpose is simply to know if a user printed a page ... we want them to do this.

Comment: @kyle:  +1 for unintedned sense of humor

Answer (score 20):

@Tahir Akhtar had the idea of using a print stylesheet. According to the comments, that doesn't work because the stylesheet is always fetched , regardless of whether the browser currently is in print view or not.

How about taking this further: Use a print stylesheet and define a style in it that *makes the browser fetch a certain resource when it's rendered*. The resource would return a transparent image.

As for the choice of CSS property, `background-image` is out, because they are usually not rendered by the browser. My thought would be a `list-style-image` or a `cursor`.

I think `list-style-image` on an absolutely positioned, transparent `<ul>` might do the trick without visually altering anything (I would not dare to position the element outside the page because of possible browser optimizations cutting it away). Every access to that resource *should* come from printing a page, or a print preview.

I can't test it right now, maybe later. If anybody tries it, I'd be interested to hear whether it works.

Comment: That looks promising! Excellent idea. +1

Answer (score 8):

In Internet Explorer 5+, you can use the [`onafterprint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536788(VS.85).aspx) event, to launch an AJAX request every time the page is printed. If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could do the following:

```
window.onafterprint = function()
{
    $.post("increment_print_counter.php");
};
```

Then maybe you can use some statistics to estimate the number of times it was printed from the other browsers!

Comment: This could also be used in combination with GoogleAnalytics. Just replacing the $.post line with the appropriate bit of the GA code. This could in theory give you better context about who is printing and so on. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when the browsers would fetch the CSS when you specify them with media="print"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css"
     href="print.css" media="print">
```

If they fetch it only when the user tries to print the document than you might try a server side trick to track it.

Give it a try.

Comment: I thought about that, but I checked with Fiddler, and it looks like IE and Chrome fetch them immediately.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I wonder how caching would interact with that.

Comment: It's cool, but unfortunately it won't work. You can analyse the traffic through Fiddler. Wikipedia articles use `media=print` stylesheets, if you'd like to test it.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in IE only.

IE supports two client-side events that you can handle:  `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint`.

You can add an AJAX request in either event that will call a page server-side to, say, increment a PagePrinted counter in a database.

Answer (score 2):

For cross browser support, only if you offer to control printing, as in, adding a "display in printable format" button, which will at the minimum, show you the intent to print the page.  However, you will not be able to stop a user from printing by conventional means or detect when the page is being printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a big, obvious “Print” button to the page, that fires `window.print`, and does an AJAX request if `onafterprint` isn’t available.

It wouldn’t give you any stats about users who are just hitting Ctrl+P (and aren’t on IE), of course, but it gives you something (if you don’t mind sticking a “Print” button on the page).

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off print with CSS (no display on the body tag)
2. Have a print button on page that pops open a new print only page. You can then tie that URL to the user (provided you have some info on them)

Comment: -1:  As a user, I would be extremely unhappy if a developer made my life more difficult and confusing (by printing out a blank page on Ctrl-P) just to get some analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for most browsers there are events that can be used to track print requests.

- IE5+ supports `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint`
- Chrome9+ and Safari5.1+ support `window.matchMedia()`

See [TJ VanToll's "Detecting Print Requests with JavaScript" blog post](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) for more information.