# PHP - Check if something was print in the browser

Tags: php, printing, download, header

How can I check if something was print in the browser? I've tried headers_sent but it's for headers...
If nothing was printed i want to download a file:

```
public function download() {
    $file = null;
    $line = null;

    if(headers_sent($file, $line)) {
        /* generic exception... change that... */
        throw new Exception('Headers was sent before in file ' . $file . ', line #' . $line);
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $this->mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $this->name);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $this->size);
    readfile($this->path);
```

Thank you.

Comment: headers_sent is what you need

Comment: Your code should work as is. `headers_sent` will return true if you've output anything (provided you don't have output buffering enabled), as the first time you do PHP will send the appropriate headers for you.

Comment: headers_sent doesn't work: <?php echo 'hi'; echo headers_sent(); // no output, so it's false ... ?>

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PHP Output control functions](http://en.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to check if there was any output to the browser.

Example:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo 'something';

$output = ob_get_contents();

if (!empty($output))
{
    die('something was printed');
}
else
{
    readfile();
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Seems you don't need to call `ob_start()` first, so you could use `ob_get_contents()` to check if, for example HTML tags were opened before in a file that included your script, or not.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. After you have sent data to the client, you have no chance of finding out what gets done with that data.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148145/is-there-a-way-to-track-if-a-user-prints-a-web-page) has some workaround ideas, but none of them is anywhere near fail-safe.

Comment: I think the OP means "Is there a way to find out if something was already output to stdout.", not printing to a physical media.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way of detecting if output is already started. I suppose `headers_sent` is a way to detect that, since PHP will send the headers when it runs into the first output in the executing script.

If you need to control when the output is started, you should probably look into [output buffering control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: @Col: which manual page would that be? There is no explicit statement about detecting sent output on the `headers_sent` manual page. My explanation of PHP's behaviour should be correct and how the function can be used to derive that information. Where is the value in your comment?