# prevent form submit if window.print is cancelled

Tags: php, javascript

i have a form the prints when form is submitted
but when i cancel the print the form is still submitted.

here is some sample codes:

```
<script>  
function printpage()  
{
   window.print();
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post">  
  <input type="text" name="fname">  
  <input type="submit" onclick="printpage()">
</form>
```

Comment: As far as I know, window.print() doesn't return anything. So you can tell if they click on the button to print, but you can't tell whether they did it or not.

Comment: Inner of <form> I can't see cancel button. Where is cancel button. Another, `printpage()` function give you not a result only calling another function print() which is not covered in Javascript code.

Comment: cancel is in the print dialog..

Comment: Can't do it, you have no access to the print dialog, therefore you can't know that anything happened in it

Comment: Question duplicated. You can find some suggestions here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148145/is-there-a-way-to-track-if-a-user-prints-a-web-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said previously, `window.print()` does not return a status, and it is async. You can do tricky things like once you trigger the call to window.print, check for mouse movement (the browser would only recognize the mouse once the print dialog is closed or completed, but you have no way to know why it was closed).

Just to be clear: nothing I am laying out below solves the question: there is no way to tell if a print was cancelled programmatically in JS. These are just additional options that may give you other possibilities.

IE also supports `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` events...but no one else does.

WebKit has had a bug out there to get these kind of events for years, but its basically dead: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19937

However, if you are supporting browsers that have `window.matchMedia` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.matchMedia) available (browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia), you may have some more options. It basically provides an API to determine if the document matches a mediaQuery. Which includes, dramatic pause, a `print` event.

Something along the lines of (combining both IE's proprietary methods and `matchMedia`):

```
(function() {
    var apiMQL = null
        , triggerBeforePrint = function() {
            console.log('Firing Before Print');
        }
        , triggerAfterPrint = function() {
            console.log('Firing After Print');
        }
    ;

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        apiMQL = window.matchMedia('print');
        apiMQL.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                triggerBeforePrint();
            } else {
                triggerAfterPrint();
            }
        });
    }
    window.onbeforeprint = triggerBeforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = triggerAfterPrint;
}());
```

Just keep in mind, there's pretty much no reliable way to do this with *just* JavaScript that gives you the detail of a cancelled print vs. completed vs. failed, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

windows.print() does not return a status. You cannot know if the page is printed or not, so canceling the submit when the page is not printed is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues of not wanting a form to submit after printing a page or clicking cancel on my print. My solution was to inline my JavaScript into my print button and add a `return false;` (see code below).

`<button onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print</button>`

This prevented my form from submitting after printing or canceling. I also put my print button inside of my form:

```
<form>
<button onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print</button>
</form>
```

I only tested this is Google Chrome so not sure if this works in other browsers.

Comment: This method works well for me with MS Edge. Thank you.