# Javascript event after Print

Tags: javascript, browser

How the way get feedback from button click cancel and print.
For example, if I click cancel button, show 0, if click print show 1.

[image]

Comment: Browsers don't let you know if the user printed or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148145/is-there-a-way-to-track-if-a-user-prints-a-web-page.

Comment: it seems so StackSlave